# example for using C++ to program Baxter robot?

Tags: ros, c++, linux, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm a beginner in ROS and Baxter. I'm thinking use c++ to program my Baxter robot but I only can found the Python example in Baxter wiki. So may I know where can find those tutorial or like an example to use C++ to program Baxter robot? Thank you!

I want to let the robot able to identify the ball's color then pick up the correct color ball.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234546/example-for-using-c++-to-program-baxter-robot?/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK the SDK and API that Rethink has released only provides Python bindings (likely why you've only seen Python examples). However, the [methods that they provide](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/API_Reference) are just using simple ROS topics, services, and actions. If you want to use C++, all you need to do is create publishers, subscribers, and clients that use the appropriate communication channels (just like any other ROS node).

Another idea might include using C++ and Python simultaneously in your project. For example, in C++ you could subscribe to a camera feed and do all of your image processing. Then once you know the location of the correct color ball, you could pass that data along to a Python node (via a topic, action, or service) that uses the Rethink API to handle the arm motions.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-18**:
Thank you for your idea! it's really really useful for me!

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-23**:
Hi Jarvisschultz,
Can I ask you one more question?
If I want to use C++ node to do those image processing and location which was you suggest to me, it's that mean in my C++ node I had to include those relate MoveIt lib? for example, visual tools.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-05-23**:
MoveIt! visual tools is not for image processing. I suggest you check out the [vision_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv) metapackage for using OpenCV within a ROS node.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-23**:
ok, thank you so much. Your advice always useful for me!